# How do I disable my application to minimize/fullscreen after pressing F on my mac?

Tags: mac

So when I press F on while using an application it minimizes/fullscreens it and it's very annoying, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: F by itself doesn't do that (by default). Command CTRL F does. So either you're pressing two extra buttons, or you've changed the shortcuts, or something else.